# In the controllers.py file of odoo, how to get the json string in the post request body?

Tags: python, json, http, odoo, werkzeug

I have defined a class in the controllers.py file to receive HTTP requests. The remote server sends a POST request and the data in the request body is a JSON string.

I can get the data in the request body directly by converting the JSON string to a dictionary via method `http.request.jsonrequest`, but for now, I need to get the original JSON string in the request body directly instead of a dictionary to verify a signature.

The method(`json.dumps()`) of directly converting to JSON strings cannot be used, as the string obtained in this way is not the same as the JSON string in the original request body, which can lead to a failure when verifying the signature.

What should I do about it? Please help me. Thank you.

this is my **controllers.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import http
class CallbackNotification(http.Controller):

    def safety_judgement(self):
        """
        :return:
        """
        header = http.request.httprequest.headers.environ
        signature = header['HTTP_X_TSIGN_OPEN_SIGNATURE']
        time_stamp = header['HTTP_X_TSIGN_OPEN_TIMESTAMP']

        remote_addr = http.request.httprequest.remote_addr
        if remote_addr != '47.99.80.224':
            return

    @http.route('/signature/process/my_odoo', type='json', auth='none')
    def receive_institution_auth(self, **kw):
        """
        :param kw:
        :return:
        """
        self.safety_judgement()
        request_body = http.request.jsonrequest

        action = request_body['action']
        flow_num = request_body['flowId']
        http_env = http.request.env

        sign_process_id = http_env['sign.process'].sudo().search([('flow_num', '=', flow_num)]).id
        if action == 'SIGN_FLOW_UPDATE':
            third_order = request_body['thirdOrderNo']
            name_id_user_list = third_order.split(',')
            model = name_id_user_list[0]
            record_id = name_id_user_list[1]
            approve_user_id = name_id_user_list[2]

            if approve_user_id != 'p':
                record_obj = http_env[model].sudo(user=int(approve_user_id)).browse(int(record_id))

            sign_result = request_body['signResult']
            result_description = request_body['resultDescription']
            account_num = request_body['accountId']
            org_or_account_num = request_body['authorizedAccountId']

            sign_user_id = http_env['sign.users'].sudo().search([('account_num','=',account_num)]).id
            http_manual_env = http_env['manual.sign'].sudo()
            if account_num == org_or_account_num:
                manual_id = http_manual_env.search([('sign_process_id','=',sign_process_id),
                                                           ('sign_user_id','=',sign_user_id)]).id
            else:
                institution_id = http_env['institution.account'].sudo().search([('org_num','=',org_or_account_num)]).id
                manual_id = http_manual_env.search([('sign_process_id', '=', sign_process_id),
                                                    ('sign_user_id', '=', sign_user_id),
                                                    ('institution_id','=',institution_id)]).id


            if sign_result == 2:
                http_manual_env.browse(manual_id).write({'sign_result':'success'})
                http.request._cr.commit()
                if approve_user_id != 'p':
                    record_obj.approve_action('approved','')
                else:
                    http_env[model].sudo().browse(int(record_id)).write({'partner_sign_state':'success'})

            elif sign_result == 3:
                http_manual_env.browse(manual_id).write({'sign_result':'failed'})
                if approve_user_id == 'p':
                    http_env[model].sudo().browse(int(record_id)).write({'partner_sign_state':'failed'})

            elif sign_result == 4:
                http_manual_env.browse(manual_id).write({'sign_result':'reject'})
                http.request._cr.commit()
                if approve_user_id != 'p':
                    record_obj.approve_action('reject', result_description)
                else:
                    http_env[model].sudo().browse(int(record_id)).write({'partner_sign_state':'reject','partner_reject_reason':result_description})
```

Comment: I would add that the HTTP request method is POST, which puts a json string in the request body.

Comment: In the test environment, I use the requests package to send HTTP requests for testing,like this

 ```python
import requests
body_json = {
    'model':'hr.expense.sheet',
    'record_id':6,
    'user_id':7
}
r = requests.post('http://188.168.0.104:8069/sign/process',json=body_json,headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'})
code = r.status_code
```

I use the ```http.request.httprequest.data```to get an empty string, could it be related to my test function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dipen Shah @CoolFlash95 @Charif DZ
Hello everyone,I've found a solution to this problem.But as I lay out the solution, I hope we can understand the root cause of the problem, so let's examine odoo's source code.

[from odoo.http import JsonRequest--odoo version 10.0--line598](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/http.py)

[from odoo.http import JsonRequest--odoo version 11.0--line609](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/http.py)

In Odoo10
`request = self.httprequest.stream.read()`,then`self.jsonrequest = json.loads(request)`

In Odoo11
`request=self.httprequest.get_data().decode(self.httprequest.charset)`,then`self.jsonrequest = json.loads(request)`

We find that the `self` object of `JsonRequest` has the attribute `jsonrequest` that the type is dict.Unfortunately, the source code does not allow `self` to have 'another' attribute, which contains the original string in the request body.However,it is very easy to add the 'another' attribute,why not?

We can use `setattr` to dynamically change the methods in the source code.Let's change the method`__init__`of `JsonRequest` and add another attribute named `stream_str`.

eg.Odoo version is 10,python version is 2.7

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import logging
from odoo.http import JsonRequest
import werkzeug
import json
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def __init__(self, *args):
    """
    We have copied the method __init__ directly from the source code and added 
    only one line of code to it
    """
    super(JsonRequest, self).__init__(*args)

    self.jsonp_handler = None

    args = self.httprequest.args
    jsonp = args.get('jsonp')
    self.jsonp = jsonp
    request = None
    request_id = args.get('id')

    if jsonp and self.httprequest.method == 'POST':
        # jsonp 2 steps step1 POST: save call
        def handler():
            self.session['jsonp_request_%s' % (request_id,)] = self.httprequest.form['r']
            self.session.modified = True
            headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=utf-8')]
            r = werkzeug.wrappers.Response(request_id, headers=headers)
            return r

        self.jsonp_handler = handler
        return
    elif jsonp and args.get('r'):
        # jsonp method GET
        request = args.get('r')
    elif jsonp and request_id:
        # jsonp 2 steps step2 GET: run and return result
        request = self.session.pop('jsonp_request_%s' % (request_id,), '{}')
    else:
        # regular jsonrpc2
        request = self.httprequest.stream.read()
        
        # We added this line of code,a new attribute named stream_str contains the origin string in request body when the request type is json. 
        self.stream_str = request

    # Read POST content or POST Form Data named "request"
    try:
        self.jsonrequest = json.loads(request)
    except ValueError:
        msg = 'Invalid JSON data: %r' % (request,)
        _logger.info('%s: %s', self.httprequest.path, msg)
        raise werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest(msg)

    self.params = dict(self.jsonrequest.get("params", {}))
    self.context = self.params.pop('context', dict(self.session.context))

# Replacing the __init__ method in the source code with the new __init__ method, but without changing the source code
setattr(JsonRequest, '__init__', __init__)
```

In the definition of the routing function, we can do this.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo.http import Controller,route,request
class CallbackNotification(http.Controller):
    @route('/signature/process/my_odoo', type='json', auth='none')
        def receive_institution_auth(self, **kw):
            # When the type='json',the request is the object of JsonRequest,we can get the new attribute stream_str very easy!
            stream_str = request.stream_str
```

Now the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a raw body data, you can use the following code:

```
raw_body_data = http.request.httprequest.data
```

Comment: Sorry, this method doesn't solve the problem because what it gets is an empty string.

Comment: I've solved this problem in my answer, you can consider it.

Answer (score 0):

pychong

You can send the value from `JSON-RPC` into your `Json controller`.

Js File:
Where **pass the value** before calling the controller like this.

```
var ajax = require('web.ajax');
ajax.jsonRpc("/custom/url", 'call', {'Your Key': Your Value}).then(function(data) {
    if (data) {
        // Code
    } else {
       // Code
}});
```

Py File :
Get the data from the post like this,

```
@http.route(['/custom/url'], type='json', auth="public", website=True)
def custom_cotroller(self, **post):
    get_data = post.get('Your Key')
    # Your Customise Code
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks,Maybe this solution will solve my problem. But sorry, this HTTP request was sent to me by a third party platform and I can't ask the third party platform to send it in any way. What the third party platform owner told me is that they sent me a POST request and put a JSON string in the request body, I just need to receive the JSON string in the request body. Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: @pychong Import the request, HTTP with the required package and check on your method to this - data = request.httprequest.data and check what you find in this later we convert into JSON format

Comment: ```from odoo import http```,```data = http.request.httprequest.data```,What I got was an empty string.

Comment: I've solved this problem in my answer, you can consider it.